# Quote other people in comment and notify them

Tags: support, comment-replies

I know that the doublequote allows you to quote other posters, but is there a way to notify them that they've been quoted? What I really need is a way to make sure I get a response for something I don't understand in the first answer.

Comment: Are you trying to notify the author of an answer, or the author of a comment? If the former, just leave a comment under the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the comment reply functionality (write @user somewhere in the comment), be nice and cross your fingers. Since this is free there is no guarantee for a (another) reply...

[image]

see here for something how it works:

https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment

[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-reply

Comment: Are they notified that I've posted a comment on their answer?

Comment: @user52187 Yes, see the edit, but I might have overlooked it, sorry...

Comment: How come I can't see the @ sign at the beginning of my comment?

Comment: @user52187 Both your questions (and much much more) are answered in the [authoritative guide on comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). Please read through it.